# Google IO 2013 Geofencing: Can I trigger transitions with a BroadcastReceiver instead of an IntentService?

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing

I'm adding the new Geofencing API to my Android app, and I'd like to catch the transitions with a BroadcastReceiver.
I tried to run the Geofencing with a BroadcastReceiver instead of an IntentService, but the BroadcastReceiver is never called at all. I registered the BroadcastReceiver with an IntentFilter correctly.
This is my binding function:

```java
    private PendingIntent getTransitionPendingIntent() { 
         if(transitionPendingIntent == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, GeofenceListener.class);
            intent.setAction(GeofenceUtil.ACTION_TRANSITION_OCCURED);
            return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
               context, 
               0, 
               intent, 
               PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
            
         }
         else
            return transitionPendingIntent;
    }
```

Can someone tell me why the BroadcastReceiver is not triggered?
Why does it work with an IntentService and not with a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Is `GeofenceListener` a `BroadcastReceiver` instance? And is it registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes, GeofenceListener extends BroadcastReceiver and it's dinamically registered through Context.registerReceiver(_listener, _intentFilter)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with a BroadcastReciever instead of an IntentService. More details here:

[Android Geofence eventually stop getting transition intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505614/android-geofence-eventually-stop-getting-transition-intents/19521823#19521823)

Comment: Hello, I tried your code but didn't work for me. The geofence doesn't trigger when the app is in background, but as soon as I open the app again the Geofence is triggered. Any Idea?